# AWS S3 CLI copy by modified date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have a large database on AWS S3. I am trying to download data files which only modified on 24 June 2022 to my local workstation. I can download entire database to given path as below but how can I just download data files filtered by modified date?

```
aws s3 cp s3://database2 .
```

Answer:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket "bucket_name" --output text  --query "Contents[?LastModified>='2022-06-24'].{Key: Key}" | xargs -I {} aws s3 cp s3://bucket_name/{} .
```

Comment: Be careful... Your definition of 24-June-2022 might not be the same as Amazon S3, which stores dates in UTC. You might need to expand your search range to find the files that match your particular timezone.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "a large database on AWS S3"? Do you mean you have many _objects_ stored in an Amazon S3 bucket? How many is "large"?

Comment: Yes, that is a very large number of objects. You will find that any operation that attempts to list the contents of the bucket (eg to identify files within a given date range) will be _VERY_ slow because each API call returns a maximum of 1000 objects. Therefore, listing 80M would take 80,000 API calls. I recommend that you consider using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects. You can then identify your desired objects from that list.

Comment: Based on the above info, I've now deleted my answer - I would recommend doing what "@JohnRotenstein has advised.

Comment: Here is the correct query format for a range date (using list-objects-v2): --query "Contents[?LastModified >= '2024-02-13T00:00:00+00:00'] | [?LastModified < '2024-02-14T00:00:00+00:00']"